# MRP price field value gets divided by 1000 when MRP is greater than 999 while updating the value in Spree (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have added a field MRP to the Product and Variants template but problem is suppose if i am updating for the second time and if MRP greater than 999 means 1000 it is getting divided by thousand and giving value as 1.00 in the field. How can i solve the issue.

```
class AddMrpToVariant < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    add_column :spree_variants, :mrp_price, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 2
  end

  def self.down
  remove_column :spree_variants, :mrp_price
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you checked the MRP value is not being modified from your application layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by adding the following code into the model.

```
%w(mrp_price).each do |m|
define_method("#{m}=") do |argument|
  self[m] = Spree::LocalizedNumber.parse(argument) if argument.present?
end
```